# java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1

Tags: java, port, rmi, server

I've tried to used RMI, here is server side. at first it worked without any exception, but now after three times whenever i try to run the below code, i will get some errors

The code is:

```
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

/**
 * Created by elyas on 12/11/14 AD.
 */
public class LogicImplement extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Logic
{

    public LogicImplement() throws Exception
    {
        java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.createRegistry(6060);
        java.rmi.Naming.rebind("Object1",this);
    }

    @Override
    public int sum(int a, int b) throws Exception
    {
        int result = a + b;
        System.out.println("ana sum executed");
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            LogicImplement logicImplement  = new LogicImplement();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
}
```

The error is like this: i've tried to change the Object1 to for example Object2, but again i will get error, also i change the port number...

what is solution?

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:341)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Naming.java:177)
    at LogicImplement.<init>(LogicImplement.java:12)
    at LogicImplement.main(LogicImplement.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:147)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Answer was very simple, By default, the registry runs on port 1099. To start the registry on a different port, specify the port number on the command line. Do not forget to unset your CLASSPATH environment variable. for more information check this link: [Running the Example Programs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/running.html)

** So for fixing this code i must change the port number form 6060 to 1099

notice that: if 1099 is used by other services you have to test 1100, and if 1100 is used too, you have yo use 1101 and so on. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

There could be couple of reasons for this exception:

- You have not started your `rmiregistry` in background.
- You are trying to connect to the wrong port number.
- Your firewall maybe blocking the connections.

Comment: if it is because of firewall what should i do? what do you mean by wrong port number?

Comment: Add exceptions in firewall if it is causing problems. Wrong port number means that you might have created a registry on port say 9098 and on client side accessing it on 9099.

Comment: @DarshanLila There won't be a firewall problem on 127.0.0.1.

Comment: but you know i don't run client side, at first i run server side, at the begging of the execution i get this error, i want to say it should not be wrong port number. because the problem is from server side...

Answer (score 1):

Since this was a port number issue, there is another way to start the registry on the port number you want:

```
java.rmi.registry.Registry rmiRegistry = java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.
                createRegistry(6060); // Creates a registry on 6060
rmiRegistry.rebind("Object1",this);   // Binds to registry created on 6060
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't started the RMI Registry.

When you get past this, if it still happens when calling the remote method, see [item A.1 of the RMI FAQ](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/faq.html#domain).

Comment: how should i start RMI Registry? I didn't get you :(